# Сортировка массива с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Привет!

Как можно рассортировать такой массив? Нужно из одинаковых 'fname' сделать один, и, смержить значения подмассивов 'values' у этих массивов с одинаковым 'fname'

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ruleId' => int 59
      'featureId' => int 93
      'fname' => string 'Особенность 1' (length=45)
      'type' => string 'checkbox' (length=8)
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          'valueCode' => int 1
          'valueName' => string 'да' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ruleId' => int 61
      'featureId' => int 84
      'fname' => string 'год' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'list' (length=4)
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          'valueCode' => int 2003
          'valueName' => string '2003' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ruleId' => int 63
      'featureId' => int 93
      'fname' => string 'Особенность 1' (length=45)
      'type' => string 'checkbox' (length=8)
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          'valueCode' => int 0
          'valueName' => string 'нет' (length=6)
```

T.e. хотелось бы понять как сделать что-то типа вот такого из имеющегося

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ruleId' => int 59
      'featureId' => int 93
      'fname' => string 'Особенность 1' (length=45)
      'type' => string 'checkbox' (length=8)
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          'valueCode' => int 1
          'valueName' => string 'да' (length=4)
        array (size=2)
          'valueCode' => int 0
          'valueName' => string 'нет' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ruleId' => int 61
      'featureId' => int 84
      'fname' => string 'год' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'list' (length=4)
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          'valueCode' => int 2003
          'valueName' => string '2003' (length=4)
```

Comment: а с остальными полями что делать?

Comment: @teran поправил описание.

Comment: вопрос был про то, что ruleId разные. Который оставляем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код не проверен, но в целом как то так:

```
$result = [];
foreach($ruleData as $d){
    $fn = $d['featureName'];
    if(array_key_exists($fn, $result)){
        $result[$fn]['values'][] = $d['values'];
    }
    else {
        $d['values'] = [ $d['values'] ];
        $result[$fn] = $d;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Супер, работает. Немного поправил :)

Answer (score 1):

Это не сортировка, а группировка

```
$in = [исходный массив];
$out = [];

foreach($in as $element){
    if(isset($out[$element['fname']])){
        $out[$element['fname']]['values'][] = $element['values'];
    } else {
        $out[$element['fname']] = $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо! Работает, но немножечко не так как нужно :)